# nfs issue when mounting kube volumes

Tags: postgresql, nfs, kubernetes

Dears, I am using using nfs to make data persist  on postgresql deployement
The deployment file looks like this

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: postgres-deployment
spec:
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: postgres
  replicas: 1 # tells deployment to run 2 pods matching the template
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: postgres
    spec:
      containers:
      - name: postgres
        image: postgres:10.4
        ports:
        - containerPort: 5432
        envFrom:
        - configMapRef:
            name: postgres-config
        volumeMounts:
        - mountPath: /var/lib/postgresql/data
          name: postgredb
      volumes:
      - name: postgredb
        persistentVolumeClaim:
            claimName: nfs-pvc
```

When the deployement start, it successes. However when I try to connect the service (exposed with NodePort)  I get this

```
psql -h XXXX --port=31329
psql: error: FATAL:  could not open relation mapping file "global/pg_filenode.map": Stale file handle
```

It looks like a permission issue, so I analysed the nfs mounted and  exported forder and I got this

```
root@nginx-deployment-6ff6548d78-45zkq:/# ls -l  /var/lib/postgresql/
ls: cannot access '/var/lib/postgresql/data': Stale file handle
total 0
d????????? ? ? ? ?            ? data
```

and

```
[admin@ip-XXXXX ~]$ sudo ls -l  /srv/nfs/postgres/
[sudo] password for admin: 
total 56
-rw-------. 1 systemd-coredump input     3 Mar  4 17:33 PG_VERSION
drwx------. 6 systemd-coredump input    54 Mar  4 17:34 base
drwx------. 2 systemd-coredump input  4096 Mar  4 17:37 global
drwx------. 2 systemd-coredump input     6 Mar  4 17:33 pg_commit_ts
drwx------. 2 systemd-coredump input     6 Mar  4 17:33 pg_dynshmem
-rw-------. 1 systemd-coredump input  4535 Mar  4 17:34 pg_hba.conf
-rw-------. 1 systemd-coredump input  1636 Mar  4 17:33 pg_ident.conf
drwx------. 4 systemd-coredump input    68 Mar  4 17:38 pg_logical
```

it seems that the conflict is due to **systemd-coredump** user  and **input** group on the nfs server.

Can you help please

Comment: "stale file handle" could mean that the the NFS share was removed and recreated on the server after the pod mounted the share. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20105260/what-does-stale-file-handle-in-linux-mean. If you control the NFS server, you should know what happened there. Regarding file ownership: The files are owned by systemd-coredump/input now, but may have been owned by a user/group that was removed, and its UID/GID was given to systemd-coredump/input.

Comment: It was that. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Your deployment file has this entry:

```
 volumeMounts:
        - mountPath: /var/lib/postgresql/data
```

Check if the NFS  exists. This is mostly due to missing mount path. Do a `ls -l <mountPath>`. That should also give you a `Stale file handle` error.